# python requests error 422

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to post a request structure over rest api.

My code:

```
def pack_orders(self, orderItemId, invoiceDate, invoiceNumber, tax, serialNumbers=None, subOrderItemId = None, subSerialNumbers = None, subInvoiceDate = None, subTax = None):
    url = "https://api.flipkart.net/sellers/orders/labels"
    payload = {[{"orderItemId": orderItemId,
                "serialNumbers": serialNumbers,
                "invoiceDate": invoiceDate,
                "invoiceNumber": invoiceNumber,
                "tax": tax,
                "subItems": [{
                    "orderItemId": subOrderItemId,
                    "serialNumbers": subSerialNumbers,
                    "invoiceDate": subInvoiceDate,
                    "tax": subTax}]
                }],}
    return self.session.post(url, params=payload)
```

calling the above function:

```
label = fk.pack_orders(orderItemId='232519872', invoiceDate='2015-08-13',       invoiceNumber='INVSTR01', tax=5)
print label.status_code
print label.url
print label.content
```

It throws error 422. I know it has to do something with the requests parameter structure. I am unable to pinpoint the source of error.

Here is a link to documentation for any help.
[Documentation](https://seller.flipkart.com/api-docs/order-api-docs/OMAPIRef.html#post-orders-labels)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

API is expecting data in `JSON` format.
Also python **[requests](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests)** is simple and easy to use.

```
import requests

data = {[{"orderItemId": orderItemId,
                "serialNumbers": serialNumbers,
                "invoiceDate": invoiceDate,
                "invoiceNumber": invoiceNumber,
                "tax": tax,
                "subItems": [{
                    "orderItemId": subOrderItemId,
                    "serialNumbers": subSerialNumbers,
                    "invoiceDate": subInvoiceDate,
                    "tax": subTax}]
                }],}

r = requests.post(url, json=data)
r.status_code
r.json()
```

**Sample requests (using shell):**

Successfully made the request. Got 401 for invalid authentication (for obvious reason)

```
In [19]: import requests

In [20]: url = "https://api.flipkart.net/sellers/orders/labels"

In [21]: data = [{
   ....:     "orderItemId": 1179576,
   ....:     "serialNumbers": ["IMEI1-UNIT1"],
   ....:     "invoiceDate": "2014-08-29",
   ....:     "invoiceNumber": "INV-01",
   ....:     "tax": 100.98,
   ....:     "subItems": [{
   ....:         "orderItemId": 1173467,
   ....:         "serialNumbers": [ ],
   ....:         "invoiceDate":  "2014-08-29",
   ....:         "tax": 10.98
   ....:     }]
   ....: }]

In [22]: r = requests.post(url, json=data)

In [23]: r.status_code
Out[23]: 401

In [24]: r.json()
Out[24]: 
{u'error': u'unauthorized',
 u'error_description': u'An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext'}
```

Comment: it says unhashable type list

Comment: My bad. Change this from `json.loads(data)` to `json.dumps(data)`

Comment: Added sample data for reference.

Comment: Note that `requests` methods accept a `json` argument these days that a) encode a Python structure to JSON and b) sets the Content-Type header for you: `r = requests.post(url, json=data)`

Comment: @ParagTyagi-morpheus-: it is for either; `requests` is an external library. Support for the `json` keyword was added in `requests` version 2.4.2.

Comment: I appreciate this answer, I got stuck in this for 2 hours since I don't know `request payload` request `json` format, you save my life!

Answer (score 0):

You should try:

```
return self.session.post(url, data=payload)
```

instead of

```
return self.session.post(url, params=payload)
```